# what is the image of $z/|z|$ where z is complex

Tags: complex-numbers

what is the image of $z/|z|$ where z is complex?

I know it is the unit circle . 
and that in R it means the sign (1, -1)

but what is it on the complex numbers? 
is it $\Re_+$ or is it $S^1$?

also - i need to know what is the Ker of $z/|z|$ where the image is $S^1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is $S^1$. You can easily prove it.

If we regard $f(z) = z/|z|$ as a homomorphism between the multiplicative group $\Bbb{C}^\times$ and $S^1 = \{z \in \Bbb{C}: |z| = 1\}$, we can talk about its kernel and $\ker f$ is the set of all positive real numbers.